# How to implement AutoFocus in Camerapagerenderer in Android xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, autofocus

I've used CameraPageRenderer where there is no implementation of AutoFocus. I don't know how to implement it in Xamarin Android.

```
public async void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
            textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            surfaceTexture = surface;

            camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
            PrepareAndStartCamera();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CameraPageRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage), setup the "Focus Mode" in the Camera properties by implementing `IAutoFocusCallback` in `CameraPageRenderer`.

```
  public class CameraPageRenderer : PageRenderer, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener, IAutoFocusCallback
{
```

Then implementing OnAutoFocus method, setting AutoFocus.

```
 public void OnAutoFocus(bool success, Camera camera)
    {
        var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.FocusMode != Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture)
        {
            parameters.FocusMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;

            if (parameters.MaxNumFocusAreas > 0)
            {
                parameters.FocusAreas = null;
            }
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            camera.StartPreview();
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I following this thread([How to implement visual indicator when camera is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025563/how-to-implement-visual-indicator-when-camera-is-focused/41053193#41053193)), to add AutoFocus for CameraPageRenderer.

```
  private void TextureView_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (camera != null)
        {
            var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
            camera.CancelAutoFocus();
            Rect focusRect = CalculateTapArea(e.Event.GetX(), e.Event.GetY(), 1f);

            if (parameters.FocusMode != Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto)
            {
                parameters.FocusMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeAuto;
            }
            if (parameters.MaxNumFocusAreas > 0)
            {
                List<Area> mylist = new List<Area>();
                mylist.Add(new Android.Hardware.Camera.Area(focusRect, 1000));
                parameters.FocusAreas = mylist;
            }

            try
            {
                camera.CancelAutoFocus();
                camera.SetParameters(parameters);
                camera.StartPreview();
                camera.AutoFocus(this);

                MarginLayoutParams margin = new MarginLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
                margin.SetMargins(focusRect.Left, focusRect.Top,
                    focusRect.Right, focusRect.Bottom);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(margin);
                layoutParams.Height = 200;
                layoutParams.Width = 200;
                takePhotoButton.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                takePhotoButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            //return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //return false;
        }
    }
private Rect CalculateTapArea(object x, object y, float coefficient)
    {
        var focusAreaSize = Math.Max(textureView.Width, textureView.Height) / 8; //Recommended focus area size from the manufacture is 1/8 of the image
        int areaSize = focusAreaSize * (int)coefficient;

        int left = clamp(Convert.ToInt32(x) - areaSize / 2, 0, textureView.Width - areaSize);
        int top = clamp(Convert.ToInt32(y) - areaSize / 2, 0, textureView.Height - areaSize);

        RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, left + areaSize, top + areaSize);
        Matrix.MapRect(rectF);

        return new Rect((int)System.Math.Round(rectF.Left), (int)System.Math.Round(rectF.Top), (int)System.Math.Round(rectF.Right), (int)System.Math.Round(rectF.Bottom));
    }

    private int clamp(int x, int min, int max)
    {
        if (x > max)
        {
            return max;
        }
        if (x < min)
        {
            return min;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public void OnAutoFocus(bool success, Camera camera)
    {
        var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.FocusMode != Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture)
        {
            parameters.FocusMode = Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;

            if (parameters.MaxNumFocusAreas > 0)
            {
                parameters.FocusAreas = null;
            }
            camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            camera.StartPreview();
            
        }
        if(success)
        {
            Task.Delay(1000);
            this.takePhotoButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
       
    }
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: also do needful for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738018/how-to-solved-programatically-like-pinch-zoom-in-zoom-out-camerapagerenderer-in?noredirect=1#comment121481574_68738018

Comment: there is no proper answer above stackoverflow link regarding for these question do needful for propert answer in xamarin android, if u know. thanks

Comment: @newxamarin If you have best solution, you can share it here.

Comment: Bu -MSFT am not found any best solution regarding these issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738018/how-to-solved-programatically-like-pinch-zoom-in-zoom-out-camerapagerenderer-in?noredirect=1#comment121481574_68738018

Comment: Please click that link

Comment: @newxamarin sorry for misunderstanding your problem, suggest you can try to implementing `IAutoFocusCallback` in `CameraPageRenderer`, please see my update.

Comment: thanks a lot for reponse, any solution for these 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738018/how-to-solved-programatically-like-pinch-zoom-in-zoom-out-camerapagerenderer-in?noredirect=1#comment121481574_68738018

Comment: @newxamarin yes, I will take a look, but my reply can answer your problem?

Comment: OnAutoFocus Method when it will call, whenever i touch it will focus on autofocus in textureview or anyother area

Comment: @newxamarin Don't understand what your mean, I test my code, and camera will Autofocus when I touch TextureView, just like take photo using camera, please see my screenshot.

Comment: Bu it will focus Off of the screen only 50% like top to center view how to focus full screen

Comment: @newxamarin I use Android device camera, it also can not focus on camera bottom. Don't know why, maybe Android device restrict.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Camera API 1 (the old one) you can set the focus mode to continuous like this:

```cs
public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
{
    try
    {
        var camera = Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
        var parameters = camera.GetParameters();

        //SET FOCUS MODE HERE
        parameters.FocusMode = Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;

        camera.SetParameters(parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log error
        return;
    }

    //other code related to the camera
    textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    surfaceTexture = surface;

    camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
    PrepareAndStartCamera();
}
```

Comment: i am using above code, once camera button tapped white screen appear and app force close

Comment: why its occur? if any other way to achieve

Comment: @newxamarin that depends on what else you're doing in the code. It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing all the code. Can you post a sample or at least the contents of your CameraPageRenderer.cs file?

Comment: Added above other part is photoclicked event stuff