# How to solved programatically like pinch zoom in, zoom out CameraPagerenderer in android xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've used CameraPageRenderer where there is no implementation of Pinch Zoom in and Zoom out. I don't know how to implement it in Xamarin Android.

```
public class PhotoCameraPageRenderer : PageRenderer, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
{
}
```

There is no implementation in zoomin and zoomout in my renderer how to handle it

Comment: Your question makes no sense whatsoever please add details to it so its easier for us to understand the issue

Comment: @FreakyAli i have using camerapagerenderer since there is no implementation in Zooming functionality in renderer when user cannot zoomin and zoomout when taking photos

Comment: @newxamarin I suggest you can use `Xamarin Community Toolkit CameraView` to display a preview of the camera output, and use `Slider` to zoom in and zoom out cameraview. one sample you can take a look:https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Views/CameraViewPage.xaml

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT actually achieved other way but actually one issue now am facing pls see this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793775/whenever-i-touch-two-my-two-finger-using-pich-to-zoomin-and-zoomout-color-appear

Comment: @newxamarin You also post one thread that about zooming in and zooming out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799406/when-we-try-to-zoomin-and-zoomout-on-xamarin-android-several-color-shades-are-o