# Whenever i touch two my two finger using pich to zoomin and zoomout color appeared Android Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, pinchzoom, autofocus

[![enter image description here][1]][1]i have to new implementation in my camerarenderer zoomin and zoomout, zoomin and zoomout working properly but color appeared if i try to zoomin and zoomout color appeared whenever i touch pich to zooming i dont know its occur. why its occur is this anything wrong in my code

````
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
            {
                
                switch (e.Action & MotionEventActions.Mask)
                {
                    case MotionEventActions.Down:
                        oldDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                        break;
                    case MotionEventActions.Move:
                        float newDist = getFingerSpacing(e);
                        if (newDist > oldDist)
                        {
                            //mCamera is your Camera which used to take picture, it should already exit in your custom Camera
                            handleZoom(true, camera);
                        }
                        else if (newDist < oldDist)
                        {
                            handleZoom(false, camera);
                        }
                        oldDist = newDist;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
    
    private void handleZoom(bool isZoomIn, global::Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
            {
                global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();
                if (parameters.IsZoomSupported)
                {
                    int maxZoom = parameters.MaxZoom;
                    int zoom = parameters.Zoom;
                    
                    if (isZoomIn && zoom < maxZoom)
                    {
                        zoom++;
                    }
                    else if(zoom > 0)
                    {
                        zoom--;
                    }
                    parameters.Zoom = zoom;
                    camera.SetParameters(parameters);
        PrepareAndStartCamera();
                }
                else
                {
                    Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", "zoom not supported");
                }
            }
        private static float getFingerSpacing(MotionEvent e)
            {
         if(e.PointerCount==2)
    {
               int pointerIndex = e.FindPointerIndex(_activePointerId);
                float x = e.GetX(pointerIndex);
                float y = e.GetY(pointerIndex);
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
        }
    
    ```
    private void PrepareAndStartCamera()
            {
                try
                {
                    camera.StopPreview();
    
                    var display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
                    if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0)
                    {
                        camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                    }
    
                    if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270)
                    {
                        camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
                    }
    
                    camera.StartPreview();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
    
                }
            }

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5axi.jpg
````

Comment: Please be as exact as you can, about what steps you did, and what happened. "zoomout not working some properly". That is not clear. 1) Does it sometimes work, sometimes not? Does it sometimes do nothing?  2) Think of changes you can make to your code, to isolate what is wrong. For example, if you hardcode it so that it ALWAYS zooms out, does that work consistently? If it does, then add to your question an alternative version of code that always zooms out.  If you can isolate exactly which line(s) of code are wrong, then it is easier to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Also describe how and where you touched the screen. And then what direction you moved the finger. getFingerSpacing is only written to look at value of ONE finger, so zoom in/out will depend on what direction you move that finger.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Edited and above screenshot also added

Comment: See if you can use [ScaleGestureDetector Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.views.scalegesturedetector) on this view. Should be able to use that on any Android native view.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  pls can u share the piece of code

Comment: Sorry, I've only worked on cross-platform views. I don't know how to do that on android camera view. I found that by googling. I don't know if it will help avoid the colors. Just a different approach to try. Maybe you can find an example with code?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i call these preparestartcamera in handlezoom colors not appear once i saved image set to defaultsize added above

Comment: Please refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755703/how-to-do-when-taking-before-picture-zoomin-and-zoomout-camerrenderer-android-xa